# Speeding up NLTK POS Tagger in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

So I'm trying to use the nltk Stanford POS tagger on a pandas dataframe column. It's a column of strings and I'm trying to extract the number of nouns in each string. Here's what I have:

```
from nltk.tag.stanford import POSTagger
from collections import Counter
import os
java_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin/java.exe"
os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path
st = POSTagger('.../stanford-postagger-2015-04-20/models/english-left3words-distsim.tagger', 
                '.../stanford-postagger-2015-04-20/stanford-postagger.jar')

def noun_count(x):
    listoflists = st.tag(x.split())
    flat = [y for z in listoflists for y in z]
    POS = [row[1] for row in flat]
    c = Counter(POS)
    nouns = c['NN']+c['NNS']+c['NNP']+c['NNPS']
    return nouns
```

I then try using apply to run it on a dataframe to create a new column.

```
df['noun_count'] = df['string'].apply(lambda row: noun_count(row),1)
```

And it does work... after awhile. Like, at least an hour, probably longer, I stopped watching it after that. Is there a way to speed things up? The thing I'm noticing with it is that it seems to call the .jar file and close it for each entry, of which I have quite a few (the task manager keeps showing java starting and stopping). Any ideas to make this work faster?

Comment: For a start there is a built in `str.split()` which is vectorised so you could eliminate that from your code so `df['word_split'] = df['string'].str.split()` and then call apply on this column and change your line in your func to this `listoflists = st.tag(x)`

Comment: Thanks for that, I adjusted those lines about half-an-hour ago (still running), but the bulk of the problem's still there. I assume the tagger has to call the .jar file each time, and it's not possibly to have the model stay internal to python. I mean, my data set's about 3000 entries, which doesn't seem excessive, but maybe for this tagger it is.

Comment: No idea really, but I glanced at the postagger documentation and it looks like there are some java options on the function call.  Maybe one of those will hold the jar open and not repeatedly call it?  It must be common to call this function for an list/array/dataframe so there must be some reasonably fast way to do this.